# Optional groups of properties ("optional intersection")

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to define optional **groups** of properties?
For example:

```js
type GetQueryParams = {
    a: string,
    b?: string,
    c?: string          
};
```

Can type be defined so that `a` and `b` would be valid only "all or nothing". I mean `{ a }` or `{ a, b, c }` is OK, but `{ a, b }` or `{ a, c }` or `{ b, c }` is not.
I know it's possible to nest

```js
type GetQueryParams = {
    a: string,
    opt?: {
        b: string,
        c: string
    }           
};
```

but I'd like to keep it flat.

**UPDATE**
Please note, there are can be **any number** of optional groups. For example:

```js
type GetQueryParams = {
    // need firstName + secondName, or none of this
    firstName?: string,
    secondName?: string,
    
    // need houseNum + flatNum, or none of this
    houseNum?: number,
    flatNum?: number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got this code from this guy https://github.com/maninak/ts-xor/blob/master/src/types/Xor.type.ts

```js
type Without<T, U> = {
  [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never;
};
type XOR<T, U> = T | U extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;
type a = { a: string };
type abc = { a: string; b: string; c: string };

type foo = XOR<a, abc>;
let bar: foo = { a: 'asd' };
```

Comment: It's work bookmarking, but not what is my question all about, as it works only for single group, while I need generic solution

Comment: Than I don't thin that you can do this while keeping it flat.